# Using ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter for variable length whitespace

Tags: powershell

I have a report that generates a CSV file of Windows Security events. With this report, I want to pull specific information.

The following below code parses each line of data by whitespace between fields. This is working correctly:

```
$InStuff = Get-Content -Path 'SecurityEvents.csv'

$ColCount = $InStuff[1].Split(' ').Count

$Collection = $InStuff | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header     (1..$ColCount).ForEach({"Column_$_"})

$Collection |
    Select-Object -Property 'Column_17', 'Column_83'
```

Sample rows of CSV:

```
<134>Dec 13 13:50:23 10.137.119.42 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 Thu Dec 13 13:50:23 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy625 N/A Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy625 Account Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
<134>Dec 13 13:50:18 10.137.119.42 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 Thu Dec 13 13:50:18 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy626 N/A Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy626 Account Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
<134>Jan  4 13:50:14 10.137.118.22 MSWinEventLog 1 Security 123456789 Thu Dec 13 13:50:14 2018 4662 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing MyCompany\dy627 N/A Success Audit mydc1.dy625.com Directory Service Access  An operation was performed on an object.    Subject :   Security ID:  S-123456  Account Name:  dy627 Account Domain:  MyCompany   Logon ID:  XXXXXXXX   Object:   Object Server:  DS   Object Type:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Object Name:  %{XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}   Handle ID:  0x0    Operation:   Operation Type:  Object Access   Accesses:  Write Property  Access Mask:  0x20   Properties:  Write Property {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX} {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}  {XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}   Additional Information:   Parameter 1:  -   Parameter 2:   123456
```

An unforseen issue is that Windows does not format their dates as I expected. For example, see below

```
<134>Dec 13
<134>Jan  4
```

If you notice, there are two whitespaces between 'Jan' and '4', while there is one whitespace between 'Dec' and '13'. This means that I require two different scripts to run, depending on the day of the month.

I was wondering if it possible to make delimiters "variable" whitespace, rather than a single defined `' '` in this specific instance. It looks like this functonality is not supported within the `ConvertFrom-Csv` command - and I'm not sure how I'd rewrite my code to accommodate this.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I will shamelessly reach out to you as you are familiar with this code and have been incredibly helpful in the past.

Comment: This is a Fixed-Width csv. Question: Does the csv use headers from which to derive the field widths?

Comment: @Theo - I actually am so inexperienced I am unable to answer your question. The data is all generated within one column. But, at this time, T-Me has provided me a proper solution.

Comment: I saw that, but if ever you need to do more with the actual data, splitting on the space character will create **7** fields for the **one** field `An operation was performed on an object.`. In a Fixed-Width file, every field has e predefined character length (width). When you know these widths per field, you can convert to a more "normal" comma delimited CSV file which would make importing it a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to add another step that replaces "two or more whitespace chars" with one space. something like this ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$Test = @'
dec 13 qwerty
jan  4 asdfgh
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$Test -replace '\s{2,}', ' ' |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header 'One', 'Two'
```

output ...

```
 One Two
 --- ---
 dec 13 
 jan 4
```

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Hey man, thanks for the help. Yes, my code is working again - and it's not dependent on the date anymore!

Comment: @dy625 - kool! glad to know you got it working ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Theo - argh! [*blush*]  i meant to use `{2,}` but posted the wrong version [`{1,2}`]. thank you for the headsup on that! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, `\s{2,}` is in fact more to the point than my `\s+`. I see you've edited yoour answer, so I'll remove my comment

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all double white spaces with a single one:

```
$InStuff = $InStuff.Replace('  ',' ')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working great, and it's a lot less messy!